# How should we tag questions dealing with expansions of games?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently on the site we have 32 questions tagged under [cataclysm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cataclysm) and 11 questions tagged under [expansions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expansions). Similarly, with DLC, we have some questions for Fallout:NV:Dead Money [tagged as fallout-new-vegas + dead-money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-new-vegas+dead-money) and others [tagged as fallout-new-vegas + dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-new-vegas+dlc). One uses the specific name of the expansion or DLC whereas the other uses the much more general categorization tag.

Since we have relatively few of these at the moment, but presumably many more on the way in 2012 with the release of the Starcraft expansion Heart of The Swarm, I figure now would be a good time to unite these questions under one tagging convention.

How should we tag questions involving game expansions or expansion-ish DLC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dlc name by itself makes for a poor tag (would you use [beat-hazard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beat-hazard) [ultra](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra)?).

Just like we've used [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone), I think [fallout-dead-money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-dead-money) or [wow-cataclysm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wow-cataclysm) is what we should be using.

Comment: I think this makes sense. I think we should also reserve the dlc/expansion tags for when the DLC/Expansion is very small(in-game items) or for when the question covers multiple dlcs/expansions.

Comment: I'm a little unclear: Does this policy mean we should be tagging expansions as: [game-name] [game-name-expansion-name], or just as [game-name-expansion-name]? (i.e. [fallout-3] vs. [fallout-3] [fallout-dead-money]?

Comment: @Wipqozn just the dlc tag is what I propose