# Should questions about a game's DLC be tagged with the DLC's name?

Tags: discussion, tags, sub-tags

When asking a question about a game that specifically involves some form of DLC for that game (as is the case [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60945/i-seem-to-have-explored-myself-into-a-dead-end-how-do-i-get-out)), should the game be tagged with the name of the DLC as well as the game? Or just the name of the game, and the all inclusive tag [dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc)?

While tagging the name of the DLC helps to sort the problems out from the other DLC for the game, for a game with lots of different DLC (say, [fallout-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-3)) it can cause more tags for one game than is really necessary, when you can just specify what DLC you're talking about in the question, or even in the title.

How should questions like this be tagged?

Comment: Related: *[How should we tag questions dealing with expansions of games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2535/181240)*

Answer (score 9):

In current usage, the term "DLC" usually means something which is not only downloadable (most whole games are downloadable anyway, nowadays) but is also rather small in scope. Usually DLCs offer new maps / items / characters / quests etc., but do not fundamentally change the gameplay.

Fallout 3 is actually more of an exception than the rule - its DLCs are relatively heavy-weight. But take a look at [Civilization V with its 11 DLCs](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8930/), or [Magicka with its 13](http://store.steampowered.com/app/42910/), or [Dungeon Defenders with its 17](http://store.steampowered.com/app/65800). All of them are rather minor. **I do not think such minor additions to gameplay deserve their own tag.**

I do not think a [dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) tag is appropriate either.

**I do think tags are in place when expansion packs, or "heavyweight" DLCs, are concerned.** If something significantly changes the gameplay and/or adds or changes a significant amount of content - what publishers also often call "expansion pack" instead of "DLC" - then a tag for that expansion is appropriate, especially for games in which we have a lot of tags. It's a judgement call.

Comment: The current trend is to take what would have once been an expansion pack, and split it into 3-5 separate individual pieces of 'DLC'. This is separate from the sort of minor 'New gun!' or 'Palette Swap!' DLC that a game like Magicka gets rather often. If a piece of DLC can support multiple questions, it should get a tag. If it shouldn't, there's probably no reason for the DLC tag specifically.

Comment: What about stand-alone expansions like Xenoblade 2: Golden Country? Should that be tagged with both the base game and the expansion?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If the DLC has enough content to warrant a variety of questions, it should get it's own tag.

[dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) is a bad tag and tells us nothing.

Also, the synonym of [dead-money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dead-money) to [dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) is particularly stupid and should really be undone.

Comment: There is no such synonym. *whistle*

Comment: this was pretty much my reasoning.  The Missing Link is rather beefy in content so I figured it would warrant its own tag.